# How to create multiple reactions using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, helper

hello please any one can help me I need route for multiple reactions.

this code is for one like but I need for many for example (like, love, heat,....)

something like Facebook reactions

and thank you.

CODE:

```
exports.likeAndUnlikePost = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);

    if (!post) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        success: false,
        message: "Post not found",
      });
    }

    if (post.likes.includes(req.user._id)) {
      const index = post.likes.indexOf(req.user._id);

      post.likes.splice(index, 1);

      await post.save();

      return res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: "Post Unliked",
      });
    } else {
      post.likes.push(req.user._id);

      await post.save();

      return res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: "Post Liked",
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      message: error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using express ?
I think you can create an array of reactions with id, then based on received  reaction id you can create a reaction

Comment: Please post this as a comment, not as an answer.

Comment: yes I use express but need something like the reactions of Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, replace `post.likes` with `post.reactions[req.params.reactionType]`, add param validation (and empty array creation when it does not exist) and you're good to go.

Comment: for example i need this:

reactions:[like:"123456987efzefze878798798"] after cancel like and give love reactions:[love:"123456987efzefze878798798"] and remove like

Comment: @hassenmohamed you've been given the path, now you need to do some work to update your code.